# Exceptions: Django 1.8 with MSSQL Server 2017 offline

Tags: python, sql-server, django, database, django-forms

As I'm new to Django. I have installed Django = 1.8 version. I tried with MSSQL Server 2017 which is locally installed in standalone system.
 Apart from settings.py file I had not modified anything. It is showing ImproperlyConfigured: Django 1.11 is not supported even though i had used Django 1.8 version.

#### **Settings.py**

> ```
> DATABASES = {
>     'default': {
>         'ENGINE': 'django_pyodbc',
>         'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
>         'NAME': 'demo2016',
>         'USER': '',
>         'PASSWORD': '',
>         'PORT': '',
>         'OPTIONS': {
>             'driver': 'ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server',
>         },
>     }
> }
> ```

```
    C:\Users\Vitriv-Desktop\Desktop\sqldjango>python manage.py migrate
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\Vitriv-Desktop\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 364, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\Vitriv-Desktop\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 338, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "C:\Users\Vitriv-Desktop\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 27, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Users\Vitriv-Desktop\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 108, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "C:\Users\Vitriv-Desktop\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 202, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "C:\Users\Vitriv-Desktop\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\Vitriv-Desktop\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\models.py", line 4, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
  File "C:\Users\Vitriv-Desktop\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\base_user.py", line 52, in <module>
    class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):
  File "C:\Users\Vitriv-Desktop\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 124, in __new__
    new_class.add_to_class('_meta', Options(meta, app_label))
  File "C:\Users\Vitriv-Desktop\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 325, in add_to_class
    value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
  File "C:\Users\Vitriv-Desktop\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\options.py", line 214, in contribute_to_class
    self.db_table = truncate_name(self.db_table, connection.ops.max_name_length())
  File "C:\Users\Vitriv-Desktop\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\__init__.py", line 33, in __getattr__
    return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
  File "C:\Users\Vitriv-Desktop\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 211, in __getitem__
    backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
  File "C:\Users\Vitriv-Desktop\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 115, in load_backend
    return import_module('%s.base' % backend_name)
  File "C:\Users\Vitriv-Desktop\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "C:\Users\Vitriv-Desktop\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django_pyodbc\base.py", line 98, in <module>
    raise ImproperlyConfigured("Django %d.%d is not supported." % DjangoVersion[:2])
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Django 1.11 is not supported.
```

How should I try to resolve the above issue?

Comment: Perhaps you forgot to activate the correct virtual environment where you installed Django 1.8, or maybe another of your requirements caused Django to be updated to Django 1.11.

Comment: @Alasdair So I had removed all the previous version of my Django and kept the new version of Django 1.11. But still the error has not resolved. How to run migrate command after setting the Database configuration. Is there any other requirements to be satisfied.

Comment: Sorry but I don’t understand your question. As the error says, it’s not going to work with Django 1.11